# Books you would like to see translated into English

Tags: books, big-list, translation

I have recently been told of a proposal to produce an English translation 
of Landau's *Handbuch der Lehre von der Verteilung der Primzahlen*, and
this prompts me to ask a more general question:

> Which foreign-language
>   books would you most like to see translated into English?

These could be classics of historical interest, books you would like your 
students to read, books you would like to teach from, or books of use in 
your own research.

Comment: The Russian translation of Milnor's Morse Theory. That's a nice book. :)

Comment: @Ryan Could you please explain me the meaning of your smile? Russian translation of Milnor's Morse theory was done by V.I. Arnol'd and it is indeed a beautiful and perfect etc translation (you don't feel that it is a translation when you read it), but it is just a translation (I''ve seen the original, sure it is also beautiful)...

Comment: I have both the original and the Russian translation.  They're not quite the same -- the translation (that I have anyhow) has more examples and figures.  

Comment: I also have both of them! And I've just check (fast checking) that pictures are absolutely same. Russian version contains small attachments (by Anosov), but they are not... as good as the book and really short, few pages. You know, translation should be a translation (I am sure Arnol'd could add smth interesting to Milnor, I am a student of V.I., but it is not the case).

Comment: It seems we're in agreement only we're not quite saying it in the same way. 

Comment: At least I understood a meaning of your smile!

Comment: Another interesting question along these lines: which books "lose" the most in translation? I can't read Russian, but apparently Kostrikin's "Around Burnside" is like that.

Comment: It was (during the 20th century) assumed that all mathematicians read English,French,German.  Probably translations of French & German books from that period will (with few exceptions) happen only when computer translationn gets good enough to do it.

Comment: I am thinking about translating a math book into English, and need help choosing one that people might actually read or find useful. Probably originally in German, Italian, Spanish, or French (roughly in that order of language ability). I'm not totally sure I will do this - it depends on finding the time. Would it be of use to begin by creating a poll from the books listed in this thread, and posting a link to it? Or just take a book from the top of this thread (like EGA/SGA)?

Comment: Is the English translation of Landau's "Handbuch der Lehre von der Verteilung der Primzahlen" completed? I'm asking since I was looking for one.

Comment: Sometimes, one might want that a book in English be translated into one's mother tongue, even if it was written by a scientist ... *3:16, Bible texts illuminated* by Donald E. Knuth will soon appear in a French edition.

Answer (score 97):

Grothendieck's EGA and SGA.

Comment: I can't help but think: if you can't manage to pick up very simple mathematical French, what hope do you have to learn Grothendieck-style algebraic geometry?  These are not books for people with poor language acquisition skills.  

Comment: Pete: I somehow suspect Dmitri does have good language acquisition skills. Dmitri: Трудно читать математические книги по-французски?   

Comment: I doubt that EGA or SGA will ever get translated given how long they are and how much background knowledge a translator would need to do a good job.  However, even though I can read mathematical French (and German, for that matter) just fine, it goes a lot slower than English.  I have to devote a portion of my mental powers to translating, and thus I can't be thinking about the math as deeply as I would otherwise!  If somehow a translation got produced, it would make this whole process a lot easier.

Comment: EGA and SGA have been translated in Russian by Manin and some others

Comment: @KConrad: I didn't mean to imply that he didn't.  He presumably speaks at least two languages already.  

Comment: I think there is a Chinese translation of EGA.

Comment: @Pete and KConrad: I fully agree with Andy Putnam on this matter.  I can read mathematical French without too much difficulty, but it goes slower than English and requires additional mental effort.  @Shizhuo: Only the introduction to EGA I was translated into Russian.

Comment: @Dmitri: I could see that the first 100 pages or so might be slower going.  But 100 pages into EGA and they're still calling Aragorn "Strider".  (Well, not literally, but you know what I mean.  Admit it, you know!)  I honestly think that after a while you get used to it.  I say this as someone who speaks precisely one language fluently.

Comment: @ Pete:  most people who read EGA/SGA aren't native speakers of French.  Even if it's not too difficult for any individual to translate, we are collectively wasting a lot of effort on repeated translations.  

Comment: @Prof. Clark: That was a particularly apt comparison and I thank you for it.

Comment: I don't know how easy the French is in EGA or SGA, but the French in Grothendieck's "Sur quelques points d'algebre homologique", the Tohoku paper, is terribly opaque. I read French well, but that paper was an exceptional challenge. I would welcome an English translation.

Comment: IMHO Hartshorne's book is sufficient for most mathematicians curious about schemes. And those who would specialize in algebraic geometry might as well learn written French.

Comment: Another reason why translations are useful is the ability to search for something electronically.  To search in the originals one must first translate the query into French, which is nontrivial.

Comment: @user N: you are absolutely right. Grothendieck for example, who presumably read EGA/SGA, was not a native speaker of French.

Comment: According to [another MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/338966) there is an [ongoing project](https://github.com/ryankeleti/ega) to translate EGA into English.

Answer (score 36):

The other two volumes of Kazuya Kato's trilogy on Number Theory (the first vol. is ["Fermat's Dream"](http://books.google.de/books?id=DdZUsjF2UToC&pg=PR13&lpg=PR13&dq=books+%22Kazuya+Kato%22+%22number+theory%22&source=bl&ots=BLndyfYlGo&sig=DiFrKmKcg67paydVYCjlNi9F5ig&hl=de&ei=XLaYS9LHNJLWmQOB1-2-Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=&f=false)).

Comment: I only regret that I have but one +1 to give to this entry.

Comment: That's +10 from me, too. 

Comment: It is at least translated to one other foreign language than Japanese.

Comment: The second one appeared recently in 2011- hopefully this means that work on the third one is in progress...

Comment: The third volume Number Theory 3: Iwasawa Theory and Modular Forms (Translations of Mathematical Monographs) was published in 2012

Answer (score 29):

"Champs algébriques" by Laumon and Moret-Bailly.

Answer (score 26):

Gabriel's dissertation,Serre's FAC and Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne

Comment: Also, Serre's dissertation. Wonderful source for spectral sequences.

Comment: For Serre's FAC see this post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14404/serres-fac-in-english

Answer (score 20):

Oh my. Since English is already so overwhelming in international scientific literature, I think it will look a bit peculiar to the non-native English speakers who read this site to see a question like this asking for *yet more* work to be put in English. Perhaps those of us who already speak that language should expend some more effort in the other direction if we want to read something in those other languages.

Comment: No, actually "non-native English speakers" would like more English translations as well. It's hard enough to learn one foreign language - learning few more just to be able to read mathematical literature feels like waste. Since just about everything is either written or already translated into English, it would be really nice to have the rest. Of course, I am not complaining - there are so many great translations into Russian I rarely see books not available in either language. In fact, there used to be even a journal with Russian translations of the best contemporary math papers... 

Comment: Yes, thank you! Actually it doesn't bother me too much that books be translated into English. I'm more concerned by the fact that fewer and fewer books are written in another language. Especially when we end up with books or articles written in a pretty bad English (meaning that even a French guy may notice something's wrong). By the way, I've always wondered: do native English speakers prefer bad English or say French (or German, etc.)?

Comment: If there is a choice available, I'd think most people would prefer something in their own language that has grammatical errors over having to read a language they are not comfortable with, particularly if the ultimate point is to get out some kind of information (like math content) rather than being concerned over the writing style itself.  

Comment: I was interpreting the end of Poineau's question to mean (bad English) versus (good French, German) rather than versus (bad French, German).

Comment: I might be strange but I find mathematics much easier to comprehend in English than in Russian, although Russian is my mother tongue and I speak/read/write it as fluently as anyone else. English is only the third and yet time after times it wins as far as mathematics is concerned.

Maybe that's because I studied mathematics in a Western environment?...

Anybody else has similar experiences?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Even though Russian is my first language, I prefer to do math in English. After getting my PhD in the US I frankly don't even know how some terms translate into Russian. It would be difficult for me to give a mathematics lecture in Russian.

Answer (score 19):

"La Clef des Songes", "Récoltes et Semailles" and the Long March through Galois Theory.

Comment: I am afraid these are (mathematically) of anecdotical interest and that Grothendieck has again recently vetoed translations and publications in any form of his magnus opus.

Comment: I respectfully doubt the Long March through Galois Theory is of anecdotal mathematical interest.

Comment: Leila Schnepps has announced [elsewhere on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466392) an English translation of *Récoltes et Semailles*.

Answer (score 17):

Hanspeter Kraft's invariant theory book.

Comment: At least this one is available in Russian (see MR0917727).    

Comment: Yuri referenced this book in a partial draft of a paper that he's written (I'm guessing he read the Russian version). I'm sure he'd be happy to talk about it.

Answer (score 17):

G.M. Fichtenholz - Analysis (3 Tomes) - *The* course of real analysis for budding mathematicians beyond the Iron Curtain. Everyone knows it. It's the first book you read, and the last one you refer to before finishing your master's degree. It takes you from the definition of a set to advanced multivariate calculus; it gives you a lot of tools for classical mechanics in the meantime. It is so trustworthy that the single wrong theorem that it contained caused a telltale student to fail his dissertation, because neither he nor his professor checked the proof and they based the whole thesis on the false premise - that was a decade or two ago and the book is, right now, free of errors. Originally in Russian. Another book that kept the Russians strong during the cold war.
[Wikipedia entry about the author](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%2C_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Comment: absolutely agreed!

Comment: Actually, as a student from Poland (where Fichtenholz is also one of the standard calculus textbooks), I find the book rather old-fashioned (and at the same time somewhat verbose).

Comment: If I recall correctly Fichtenholz has defected to the West. There is shorten two volume English version of his Analysis. However, I would cold-heartedly agree that Russian version is far better. 

I would also agree that his books are somewhat outdated. My favorite work for the first/second year Analysis undergraduate course (Eastern European version of Calc 1-3) is Vladimir Zorich's two volume book.

From the pedagogical point of view Fichtenholz books are far more appropriate for gifted high-school students.

Comment: Oh yes!! This is an awesome book. The short version actually exists also in Russian and is very good as well but the long version is so much better.

Comment: As far as I understand Vladimir Zorich's two volume book has been translated into English see <http://books.google.pl/books?id=qA5FTMT7HE4C&lpg=PP1&dq=zorich&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=zorich&f=false>

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Actually, Fichtenholz has never defected to the West. On the opposite, he was quite established in the Soviet Union, was the Chair of the Department of Mathematical Analysis at Leningrad State University, and had several state awards.

Comment: @mathreader I really appreciate your comment. I would swear I saw 2 volume English version of Fichenholz book almost 20 years ago at the University of Toledo Ohio library. The book didn't look like a translation of the Russian version I used as a student in Serbia.

Comment: Sorry, which theorem you were referring to was false? I need the section number and the statement of the theorem so that I can find it in a Chinese translation (a translation of Fizmatlit publishers Russia 2003).

Comment: @PredragPunosevac I prefer Zorich's book to Fichtenholz's. The former is much more modern and the latter is way too talkative and I prefer to use it as a reference rather than a textbook.

Comment: @Yai0Phah no idea.

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know, *none* of **Wilhelm Blaschke**'s books have ever been published in English, and he is the the author of possibly the most exciting and elegant serious mathematics books that I've ever encountered (comparable to the best of Felix Klein, but on a much higher mathematical level). I especially regret that his

*Einführung in die Differentialgeometrie* (1950; 2nd ed with Reichardt, 1960)

and

*Elementare Differentialgeometrie* (5th edition with Leichweiss, 1973)

have not been available, but really, all his books, from the elementary "Kreis und Kugel" to the state-of-the-art research "Geometrie der Gewebe" are incredible. Fortunately, most of them have been translated into Russian.

Does anyone know a credible explanation of *why* he was completely ignored in the English-speaking world? Anything to do with WWII? Although even Hasse got translated.

Comment: + "Kreis und Kugel"

Comment: As to why Blaschke has not been translated - surely one reason is that the topics he wrote about, such as web geometry or affine differential geometry, have been "unfashionable" (the quotes refer to a preprint of Burstall) in the English speaking world - i.e. US/UK. As you allude to, he was also the president of the Deutsche Mathematiker Vereingigung in the mid to late 1930s, and although was apparently not so aggressive as someone like Bieberbach, was a Nazi party member and by most accounts a supporter of that state. This surely had an effect. Teichmuller has also not been translated.

Answer (score 14):

[Endliche Gruppen](http://books.google.com/books?id=wP3uAAAAMAAJ&q=endliche+gruppen&dq=endliche+gruppen&ei=R1WYS9C3Aoe4ywTi4vjVCg&client=firefox-a&cd=3) by Huppert, though the German is like the French in EGA: "easy" going.

Answer (score 14):

I'd second Allen Knutson's suggestion that the book Geometrische Methoden in der Invariantentheorie by Hanspeter Kraft (Vieweg, 1984) is a good candidate
for translation into English.   Since AMS distributes several Vieweg series in
English versions, I'd suggest asking Sergei Gelfand at AMS whether such a
translation could be commissioned by them.

Like most native users of English, I find mathematical French far easier than
mathematical German.   In any event, French books and papers are less likely to
get translated than German ones.  As far as books go, I regret that J.C.
Jantzen's useful Springer Ergebnisse volume on primitive ideals in
enveloping algebras is not available in English.  His later books in English
have become standard references for representations of algebraic groups and
for quantized enveloping algebras.

Comment: It's fun to make a wish list, but in real life it's hard to justify
the cost of translating an advanced book for a limited market.  It's
always tricky to find a translator with the right mathematical 
as well as linguistic background, lacking which a reader may be better off struggling with the original book.    

Comment: Huge cheers for Jantzen! Not only is it not available in English, but I spent $\textit{decades}$ trying to acquire a copy - it's been out of print forever and if you go to Springer website and check Ergebnisse series, vol 3 simply does not exist! Springer & Lange (Berlin) promised to track one for me, Springer (NY) people at the JMM claimed that it would be trivial to get it, or that the volks in Springer (Heidelberg) could do it... Bottom line: it's the math book I've read the most in my life, and I still don't own it. 

Comment: On the subject of "struggling", I might add that I've practically learned all my mathematical German ploughing through Jantzen. I've also heard from a German colleague that it's written in a good language.

Answer (score 14):

[Fricke and Klein](http://books.google.com/books?id=oLArAAAAYAAJ&q=Fricke+and+Klein&dq=Fricke+and+Klein&client=firefox-a&cd=1).

Comment: These are about to be published: https://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-1/

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 12):

Don Zagier's German book about quadratic forms.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am working on a book on quadratic forms that will at least present Zagier's reduction theory in English.

Comment: That's great to hear.

Comment: The book is called "Zetafunktionen und quadratische Körper"

Comment: A version of Franz Lemmermeyer's book can be found on his website here http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/bf.pdf

Answer (score 11):

*Analysis Situs* by Poincare.

This is the foundation of algebraic topology and illustrates its historical connection with dynamics.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9#Poincar.C3.A9.27s_writings_in_English_translation) it has been translated, but I can't find a copy in English.

Comment: I don't know which translation the Wikipedia is referring to,
but I have a translation of *Analysis situs* (together with the
five *Complements*) which is going to be published by the AMS soon.
You can access a preliminary version of it on Andrew Ranicki's page:
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/notes.htm
(near the bottom of the page).

Comment: Wow! I was half-hoping that someone would comment with this response. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the current listing at the AMS bookstore:  

http://e-math.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=hmath-37

Comment: I think I have an old copy back in my library on another continent...

Answer (score 11):

Abel's complete works.

Comment: I agree that Abel's works are an excellent candidate. Like Riemann's, they are of stellar quality and not too long. In the meantime, you may be interested in the lengthy survey of Abel's work by Christian Houzel, which may be downloaded from the page:

http://www.abelprisen.no/en/abel/fagligbiografi.html

Answer (score 9):

*Groupes Algebriques* by Demazure and Gabriel. Someone tried to translate the first half of this book, but it's not very good (some of the mathematics is incorrect too).

Answer (score 8):

*Gesammelte Abhandlungen* (Collected Works) of Carl Ludwig Siegel

(According to Amazon.com a trilingual version of this once existed, but I can't find it.)

Comment: Siegel also has excellent lecture notes on analytic number theory, quadratic forms, complex analysis etc.

Answer (score 8):

Chebotarev's "Grundzüge der Galois'schen Theorie"

Answer (score 8):

G. Banaszak, W. Gajda - Elementy Algebry Liniowej (Elements of Linear Algebra), Poland, WNT - 2 tomes - Don't let the name fool you. This recent publication has more linear algebra than you can shake a stick at. It's a very comprehensive course of linear, and some abstract, algebra; very beautifully printed, lots of decorative markup. The book is very well structured, but is not easy and requires the reader to be fully aware of what's going on. It can be a bit of a mind wringer, but on the other hand that can force you to look at many things from the writers' - quite original sometimes - viewpoint.
[Tome 1 on the publisher's website](http://www.wnt.com.pl/product.php?action=0&prod_id=1526&hot=1)

This is just a quick round-up of some good books in Mathematics. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting suggestions! While on the subject of "more linear algebra than you can shake a stick at", I'd like to mention Brieskorn's Lineare Algebra und Analytische Geometrie, volumes I and II (Vieweg 1983, 1985). This is the most fascinating linear algebra book I've ever seen, but very long and rambling.

Comment: Another book I almost included in this list:
Dieudonne - Treatise on Analysis

Haven't included it because there's a (discontinued) translation to English from the 70s.

**Huge** book: some editions have more than ten tomes. **Huge** amount of knowledge. All organized nicely in an easily understood structure, with hints on how to most quickly arrive at a certain theorem. Read it all and you'll know analysis the way a PhD student should.


Dieudonne is the (often forgotten) co-author of Grothendieck's Éléments de géométrie algébrique - if one likes EGA, they'll enjoy this book as well.

Comment: I have split out this answer into separate ones for each book - John Stillwell's comment was originally for all of them in one answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Another answer contains this suggestion, but it's at the end of the answer and no details are given.]

I would rather like to read Kostrikin's *Introduction to Algebra* (the 2nd edition, published in 2000: Кострикин – *Введение в алгебру*). It is in 3 volumes: 'Basic algebra', 'Linear algebra', and 'Fundamental structures of algebra'. Approximately, they cover:

I – preliminaries, matrices & determinants, basics of groups rings & fields, complex & real polynomials

II – vector spaces & linear operators, euclidean hermitian affine & projective spaces, tensors

III – structures of various groups, basic representation theory, rings modules & algebras, Galois theory

The book begins with a discussion about what algebra is, a historical overview, and a set of substantial problems that can be solved with algebra as motivation. Each volume contains a number of figures (67 in total), many applications, and a discussion of open problems (e.g. the convergence of Newton's method, finite projective planes, the inverse Galois problem).

From the [Zentralblatt review](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an:0954.15001): "The distinguishing features of the book are the following ones: 1) clearness, clarity and compactness of exposition; 2) the concentric style of presentation; 3) variety of skilfully selected examples (from very simple to very complex ones)."

[Note that the 1st edition was translated, but it is about a third as long and covers far less.]

Answer (score 7):

"Arithmetique Des Algebres De Quaternions" by MF Vigneras

Answer (score 7):

I.N. Bronstein, K.A. Semyendayev - Mathematics Handbook - an awesome, very complete mathematics handbook for applied mathematicians, physicists, and engineers. Also useful for the pure mathematics researcher who just wants to quickly look up how a basic item in mathematics worked. This work has not lost any of its gleam since it was first written; numerous updates have been made; it is *the* reference compendium in Central and Eastern Europe. It has received prizes for being the best illustrated engineering book; indeed, the drawings are exact and even beautiful, and have not become outdated in the time of computer generated imagery. Definitely one of the books that put the Russians in outer space.
[Numerous German editions of the book on Amazon](http://www.amazon.de/B%25C3%25BCcher/s?ie=UTF8&rh=n%253A186606%252Cp_27%253AK.%2520A.%2520Semendjajew&field-author=K.%2520A.%2520Semendjajew&page=1%20%22Numerous%20german%20editions%20on%20Amazon%22)

Answer (score 7):

The following wonderful 54 page survey by O. Neumann on Kronecker's divisor theory could easily be turned into a book and would fill a very large gap in the English literature on such. I'm interested in helping if anyone is game for such (but, alas, my German is weak).

Neumann, O.(D-FSU-MI) 2003k:13021  13F05 (01A55 13G05 20M14)
Was sollen und was sind Divisoren? (German. German summary)
[What are divisors and what can we do with them?]
Math. Semesterber. * 48 (2002), no. 2, 139--192.

In the first part of this paper a survey is given of the development of
Kronecker's theory of divisors. In the second part the author develops a
theory of integral domains  $R$  having a divisor theory in the following sense:
there exists a monoid  $D$  (i.e., a commutative semigroup with cancellation and
a unit element) with the GCD-property for the associated group  $G$  of
quotients, and a homomorphism $\mathrm{div}$ of the multiplicative group  $K^*$  of the
quotient field of  $R$  into  $G$  with the following two properties:

(i)  If  $a,b \in K^*$  and  $b/a \in R$, then  $\mathrm{div}(b)/\mathrm{div}(a) \in D$, and

(ii) for every element  $d \in D$  there exists a set  $A \subseteq K^*$
     such that  $d$  is the gcd of $\{\mathrm{div}(a) : a \in A\}$.

The author states that a similar theory was presented in the thesis of 
F. Lucius ["Ringe mit einer Theorie des groessten gemeinsamen Teilers", Ph.D. 
thesis, Univ. Gottingen, Gottingen, 1996; Zbl 0901.13002]. After developing 
the fundamental properties of such divisor theory, relations to the approaches
of Kronecker, Zolotarev and Dedekind are established.
--Reviewed by W. Narkiewicz

Answer (score 6):

[Kalkül der abzählenden Geometrie](http://books.google.com/books?id=1zQAAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_slider_thumb#v=onepage&q=&f=false) By Hermann Schubert

[Lehrbuch der abzählenden Methoden der Geometrie](http://books.google.com/books?id=hnVtAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_slider_thumb#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
 By Hieronymus Georg Zeuthen

Answer (score 6):

[original suggestion/answer by Andrew L]

Constantin Carathéodory's 
*Vorlesungen über Reelle Funktionen*. Why this book has never been translated into English is simply a mystery to me.

And while he's at it, let's get whoever's on that case to get Courant and Hurewitz's treatise on complex functions into English as well, so I can see finally if it's as good as Serge Lang always said it was...

2 last requests while I'm at it: Faddeev's 1984 *Lectures In Algebra* and the second edition of Kostrikin's 3 volume *Introduction To Algebra*. I'm such a sucker for Russian texts, they're so beautiful and concrete with connections to physics. We Westerners can learn so much from their approach.

Comment: *Why this book has never been translated into English is simply a mystery to me*  Solution to the mystery... it has been assumed until recent years that all serious mathematicians know German, French, and English.


Comment: I know,Gerald-but that's never stopped some great German texts from being translated into English-such as Courant's calculus lectures or van der Wearden's algebra texts. That's no excuse,I'm sorry.And times have changed,for better or worse.The language requirement-again,for better or worse-is fading in importance.

Answer (score 6):

Équations différentielles à points singuliers réguliers, by Deligne.

Answer (score 6):

B. P. Demidovich - Problems on Multivariate Analysis (approximate translation). A very tough book about analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$; in fact all problems 'can' be solved by first- or second-year students, but it's got lots of tricky questions that will not let you sleep at night. Only the best need apply - the book gives you the most basic definitions and then throws you out with a broken pontoon in the middle of the ocean, at night. I believe the writer is Russian or Belorussian, I have only encountered a few tattered copies that have been doing the rounds between students for a decade at least. Haven't found a better book for tough multivariate analysis.

Comment: For every Demidovich there is an anti-Demidovich (proverb).

Comment: Which brings us to the suggestion: Translate anti-Demidovič (Ljaško et al.).

Answer (score 6):

Joseph Louis Lagrange - Reflexiones sur la Resolution Algebrique des Equations.  I've found lots of discussions and summaries of its contents (e.g. in Harold Edwards' book on Galois theory) and little snippets translated here and there (e.g. in Mathematical Expeditions by Laubenbacher and Pengelley) but haven't been able to locate a complete translation.

Answer (score 6):

Weber's Lehrbuch der algebra, though I see this math underflow post that already expresses this wish: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438643/translation-of-webers-lehrbuch-der-algebra-vol-1-2-3

As a textbook bridging from elementary algebra to (then state-of-the-art) research, and coming right at the border between two eras of mathematics, it would be helpful for historians of algebra and mathematics to have this text in english.

I humbly thought I was up for it a year or so ago, but obviously someone more esteemed than I should handle such a monumental translation!

(Edit: "humbly" should read "in ignorance")

Comment: One of the answers in that math.stackexchange post says the book was translated into French.  With a Google search, the French translation can be found on gallica.bnf.fr: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k92747w.image.

Answer (score 5):

[Geometrie der Gewebe](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-45/issue-9/Review-W-Blaschke-and-G-Bol-Geometrie-der-Gewebe/bams/1183502080.full) by W. Blaschke, and G. Bol

[Geradenkonfigurationen und algebraische Flächen](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=rN_yImsGho4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=hofer%20hirzebruch&source=bl&ots=7SxSeyoqmW&sig=Hd5OKS5Vrwu-eAdWf01v3WSxMc4&hl=pt-BR&ei=mUiYS_PeM4OXtgfGq8jkAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by G. Barthel, F. Hirzebruch, and T. Höfer

Answer (score 5):

Bombieri's "Le Grand Crible dans la Théorie Analytique des Nombres"

Comment: If there is any justice it should first be translated into Italian.

Answer (score 5):

The Collected Work of Carl Ludwig Siegel.

Comment: This is a duplicate; see Zavosh's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Over de Grondslagen der Wiskunde , L.E.J Brouwer, his thesis (in Dutch) on the foundations of mathematics.

Comment: Also Brouwer's other work in Dutch and German.

Answer (score 5):

Catégories et structures by Charrles Ehresmann

Answer (score 5):

Two volume introduction to Complex Analysis by B.V.Shabat. Actually, I have already translated about 150 pages of the first volume which is about as much as one can cover in Complex Variable undergraduate course offered by a typical U.S. university. I did give the translation as a hand out to my students last year when I taught Complex variables class. I did translation out of frustration with the book of Churchill and Brown.

Answer (score 5):

There are two books on popular mathematics by Polish mathematicans **Krzysztof Ciesielski** and **Zdzisław Pogoda** (both from the Jagiellonian University in Krakow): the first one is *Diamenty matematyki* [**Mathematical diamonds**] (cover http://merlin.pl/images_big/3/83-7337-932-0.jpg), the second is *Bezmiar matematycznej wyobraźni* [**The endlessness of mathematical imagination**] (I could not find a better transaltion). Both aim at non-specialist, mostly high-school students, and are written in a unique, informal yet rigorous style. Both are very popular and out of print in Poland. A modified version of a chapter in Mathematical diamonds has been translated by Abe Shenitzer and was published in the American Mathematical Monthly as ***On Ordering the Natural Numbers, or, The Sharkovski Theorem*** in **Vol. 115**, No. 2 (**Feb., 2008**), pp. 159-165.

Comment: I'd say that *Diamenty matematyki* should read *The diamonds of mathematics*.

Comment: In their Monthly article mentioned above Ciesielski and Pogoda translate Diamenty matematyki as Mathematical Diamonds in the reference lists.

Answer (score 5):

Probably most of the works from Oskar Perron. It has been mentioned already Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen, both volumes, but we could also ask for Irrationalzahlen or any of the other works from Perron.
Also worth being mentioned, for applied mathematicians, are the works of Grigory Isaakovich Barenblatt, previous to 1994; this is because Barenblatt has consistently worked about scaling phenomena, but from about the beginnings of the 1990's he began to do it on his own, whereas earlier work includes the participation of other marvelous mathematicians, like Z'eldovich; or even works on his own, but it is interesting to compare the evolution of his ideas. So, the name of books with his participation previous to the 1990's, and to my knowledge, not translated into English:
* Ja, B Zeldovich, G. I. Barenblatt, V. B. Librovich, G. M. Maxvikadze "Matematicheskaja teorija gorenija i vsriva", 1980
* G. I. Barenblatt, "Podobie, avtomodelnoct, promezhutochnaja asimptotika: teorija i prilozhenija k geofizicheskoi gidrodinamike", 1982
* A. P. Licitsin, G. I. Barenblatt "gidrodinamika i osadkoobrasovanie", 1983
* G. I. Barenblatt, V. N. Entov, V. M. Rizhik, "Dvizhenie zhidkocteii i gazov v prirodnix plactax" 1984
* G. I. Barenblatt, "Analiz razmernosteii" . Uch. pos. M.: MFTI, 1987. 168 с. (I think this last work made it to English under the translation as "Dimensional Analysis", but in that case I saw it only once, at the library of the Department of Applied Mathematics and Theoretical Physics -DAMTP-of Cambridge, UK, many years ago and is likely out of print anyway, plus the edition, to my knowledge was not revised; on top of that, DAMTP changed from Silver Street to Wilberforce road, and I have no idea if that book survived the moving, if indeed was at that library).

Notice also, that in the Nachlass (the collection of manuscripts, left after the death of an academician, and of course in particular a mathematician) of people like Bernhard Riemann or Ernst Zermelo, there might be still some untranslated documents, but then again they also need to be interpreted in a way that could be meaningful, and this because they are not finished, published or even unpublished works, but sketches of something not fully developed.

Answer (score 4):

Chirurgie des grassmanniennes by Laurent Lafforgue.

http://www.ihes.fr/~lafforgue/math/M02-45.pdf

Comment: That sounds so much cooler in French.

Answer (score 4):

O. Perron - *Die Lehre von den Kettenbruechen (Band 1-2)*

Answer (score 4):

*Riemannsche Geometrie Im Grossen* by Gromoll, Klingenberg and Meyer. I remember this book being cited by Gromov in his famous green book for further details about connections.

Comment: There is a Russian translation, by the way (by Burago).

Answer (score 4):

Hilbert's collected works are not fully translated into English. E.g. his paper 
Ueber ternaere definite Formen". Acta Math., 17 (1893), 169–197 was only translated into Russian.

Answer (score 4):

Bourbaki "Théories spectrales Ch 1-2". This also related to the MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210025/unitization-process-of-unital-and-non-unital-c-algebras/210031#210031).

Answer (score 4):

[Etienne Ghys, Pierre de la Harpe, "Sur les Groupes Hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov"](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-9167-8)

A detailed exposition of Gromov's ideas, outlined in his "Hyperbolic groups" article.

Answer (score 4):

I would really love a translation of the third russian edition of "Number Theory" by Borevich and Shafarevich. It has updated notation, revised errata and has numerous new remarks and updated bibliography. Also, the AP english translation is full of misprints. Anyone knows if there is a project of translating this beatiful book?

Answer (score 4):

I hope I did not miss that in one of the previous answers, but a book worthy of an English translation is *"Théorie des distributions"* by Laurent Schwartz. The later edition combined Vol I and II as a single book. One could also consider translating Vol III and IV which are his two long papers on vector-valued distributions. About the latter, see this related MO question: [English translation of Schwartz's papers on vector-valued distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386348/english-translation-of-schwartzs-papers-on-vector-valued-distributions)

Answer (score 3):

Friedrich Levi, *Geometrische Konfigurationen*

Answer (score 3):

Hilbert-Bernays's "Foundations of Mathematics", it's a shame that this classic work haven't translated yet!

Comment: Looks like it's under way, though: http://wirth.bplaced.net/p/hilbertbernays/. According to the relevant wikipedia page, a German/English edition of volume 1 has appeared.

Answer (score 3):

"Introduction aux groupes arithmétiques" by Armand Borel.

Answer (score 3):

I'd love to see Weil's book on Kahler geometry: Introduction à l'étude des variétés kählériennes.

Answer (score 3):

Egbert Brieskorn’s *Lineare Algebra und analytische Geometrie* - the best textbook on the topic in my POV.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the following, I want to read it just because in his books, Milnor referred to it for some proofs.

*Cerf, J.*, [**Sur les difféomorphismes de la sphère de dimension trois ($\Gamma_ 4 = 0$)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0060395), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 53. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. XII, 133 p. (1968). [ZBL0164.24502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0164.24502).

Answer (score 2):

Re: For publication of EGA and SGA, see this: http://www.grothendieckcircle.org/

Comment: Not anymore, sadly.

Comment: veit79 is referring to the following news: http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/02/grothendieck_said_stop.html

Answer (score 2):

[Teubner-Taschenbuch der Mathematik Teil II](http://www.amazon.de/Teubner-Taschenbuch-Mathematik-2-G%25C3%25BCnter-Grosche/dp/3519210088)

The first part (Teil I) of this book was translated into English as the [Oxford User's Guide to Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=iA8T471NC-cC)

Answer (score 2):

[Vorlesungen über Differenzenrechnung](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1925-31-08/S0002-9904-1925-04088-4/home.html) by [Niels Erik Nörlund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Erik_N%C3%B6rlund)

([Citations](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?cites=14147882359602159248&hl=en&as_sdt=2000))

Answer (score 2):

Einfuhrung in die Algebraische Geometrie-B.L. van der WAERDEN

Comment: See the link to _Introduction to Algebraic Geometry_ on this page: http://www.neo-classical-physics.info/geometry.html

Answer (score 2):

Durer's works on proportion, which take a Euclidean approach to constructing visible objects.

Comment: Do you mean his _Underweysung der Messung mit dem Zirckel und Richtscheyt_ (Instruction in Measurement with Compass and Straightedge)?

Answer (score 2):

Paul Gordan ``Vorlesungen ueber Invariantentheorie"
available  [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=FqRLAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=paul%20gordan%20vorlesungen%20invariant&source=gbs_book_other_versions#v=onepage&q&f=false) , both volumes.
This is most worthwhile since the content of most other classics
is well accounted for in modern texts whereas this way of doing algebraic geometry has been completely forgotten. Poor knowledge of Gordan's methods is a net loss for contemporary mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

"Quadratische Formen" by Martin Kneser.

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetique des algebres de quaternions
http://www.springer.com/kr/book/9783540099833

Comment: Well, it is mostly done here: http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387983868

Answer (score 1):

F. Prus-Wisniowski - Szeregi Rzeczywiste (Poland, Uniwersytet Szczecinski) - a monograph on real series. It can be read by first-year students while supplying the reader with very powerful tools for real (and sometimes complex) series; it might surprise the PhD reader. More importantly, it builds a good understanding of the way real series work.
[Publisher's website](http://www.us.szc.pl/main.php/katalog_wnus/?xml=load_page&st=1444&gs=13213&ks=697%20%22Publisher%20page%22)

Comment: I happen to know Prus-Wisniowski personally, and he is a fluent English speaker who also translated several Russian papers for me in the mid 1990s. You might want to consider asking him about this. I suspect a translation would fit nicely into one of the MAA book series.

Comment: Dave, what is the MAA book series? :)

Comment: I wasn't thinking of a specific book series, but since you asked, [*Classroom Resource Materials*](https://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/classroom-resource-materials) seems to be a good fit for the book. For example, the widely cited (on Math StackExchange) book [**Real Infinite Series**](https://store.maa.org/site/index.php?app=ecom&ns=prodshow&ref=MAA-RIS) is in this book series.

Comment: What is MAA though?

Comment: MAA = Mathematical Association of America, which is mostly teaching and non-research oriented, in contrast to AMS = American Mathematical Society.

Answer (score 1):

Dirk Werner, Funktionalanlysis. I love this book.

Answer (score 1):

Gerhard Thomsen's *Topologische Fragen der Differentialgeometrie XVI: Über die topologischen Invarianten der Differentialgleichung* $y^{\prime\prime} = f(x,y)(y^\prime)^3 + g(x,y)(y^\prime)^2 + h(x,y)y^\prime + k(x,y)$ Teubner Leipzig 1930.

(See A. Khovanskii *Topological Galois Theory* Springer 2014, [translated from the 2008 Russian original] for subsequent developments.)

Answer (score 1):

Dissertation of Hopf: "Über Zusammenhänge zwischen Topologie und Metrik von Mannigfaltigkeiten" (En: Connections between topology and metric of manifolds).

Answer (score 1):

Paul Lévy 1937 – Théorie de l'addition des variables aléatoires