# Books you would like to see retranslated.

Tags: books, big-list, translation

As a follow on to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17778), what books would you like to see retranslated or rewritten as the original translation wasn't very good, or can you give examples of books that have been translated more than once into the same language.

Comment: Why the downvote? I believe that this question is just perfect for MO.

Comment: I agree that Roy's question is a good supplement to mine, because
many translations are unsatisfactory. For example, there are 19th
century translations that read badly today because their terminology 
is out-of-date and their style is very longwinded.

Comment: What, exactly, is the point of this question?  If someone were offering to redo a translation then I would understand.  If someone were asking for a list of books worth reading that might have been overlooked due to not being in English (am I right in presuming that the translation is intended as being into English?  What about Norwegian?  Can I nominate bad translations from English to Norwegian?) then I would grumble but probably let it go, but I don't see the point of simply having a list of poor translations.

Comment: This question now has a meta thread - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/461/books-you-would-like-to-see-retranslated/

Comment: I admit this isn't the best question. It's basically: wouldn't be nice if these books were redone. But it's not going to happen, so let's close this question.

Comment: @Roy: I disagree with your pessimism.  Some time ago I got Klaus Evers to start a list of out-of-print math books, with the goal of finding out which out-of-print books were most in demand. http://outofprintmath.blogspot.com/  I have spent a fair amount of effort trying (and in a couple of cases succeeding) in getting the top items back into print.  MO is as good a place as any for collecting this kind of information about translations.  Someone who is willing to do translations would naturally like to know which translations would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I nominate Felix Klein's *Lectures on the Icosahedron and the Solution
of Equations of the Fifth Degree* as a book that deserves retranslation. 
The present English translation was made in 1888, and it contains a lot of 
archaic terminology, such as "permutable" for "commuting," "transformation" 
for "conjugation," and "associates" for "conjugates."  Also confusing, though 
in principle a good idea, a normal subgroup is called "self-conjugate."

Best of all, a new edition would give an opportunity to 
introduce some pictures, which are incredibly absent from Klein's original text.

Comment: Ah ha, converting the yesterwords of olde mathematicish into modern mathematicese.

Comment: Shurman's _Geometry of the Quintic_ deals at least in part with the same material: http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Quintic-Jerry-Shurman/dp/0471130176