# Where can you find Grothendieck's "Récoltes et Semailles"?

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy

Where can you find Grothendieck's "Récoltes et Semailles"?
Is it available anywhere?

Comment: It used to be avaliable at the web page of the grothendieck-circle
http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/mathtexts.php
but as you can read there "Grothendieck's writings no longer available as per his demand" and actually the fate of the web site itself is uncertain.... I am also certain that a simple google search will find a copy still avaliable on-line...

Comment: It also used to be available at http://acm.math.spbu.ru/RS/
But isn't this a question whose answer Google knows better at any moment than MO?

Comment: @Romeo: Indeed, it's offtopic. Therefore I've voted to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/RetS.pdf](http://people.math.jussieu.fr/%7Eleila/grothendieckcircle/RetS.pdf)

archived at the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141029175552/http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/RetS.pdf)

Comment: @Carlo: Rhooo... :-)

Comment: So this means that this site hosts Grothendiecks text without his permission?

Comment: They removed the links from the webpage but apparently most files are still online, look for instance http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php and http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/unpubtexts.php.

Comment: Note that the situation around permission has changed since AG passed away.

Answer (score 23):

I've just finished translating all of Récoltes et Semailles into English and it will be published by MIT Press in 2025.

Comment: Thank you ..... !

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is an immense effort, and one I've hoped would happen one day.

Answer (score 10):

Gallimard (a french book publisher) is going to publish it (in french), the release date is 11-11-2021). For more information: http://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Tel/Recoltes-et-Semailles-I-II

EDIT: at this point, we do not know if parts will be edited or even censored (for instance there are some personal attacks in the original version).

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** *Récoltes et Semailles* has just been [published](https://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Tel/Recoltes-et-Semailles-I-II) in two volumes by Gallimard.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a link with scans [[link]](http://matematicas.unex.es/%7Enavarro/res/), an ongoing transcription [[pdf]](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/ReS.pdf), and translation to spanish [[pdf]](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/CyS.pdf) (almost finished)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link on the interplanetary file system which should be much more robust: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmaWmdeyPX4dA8dHVhNN2qRtVLWqKTTVMHgHufZMUJut3F

Answer (score 3):

Mateo Carmona freshly transcribed and edited a new version, available as a 1500-page pdf at https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/ReS.pdf and it looks very nicely done.