# Récoltes et Semailles for the non (algebraic-) geometer

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, gm.general-mathematics

With the recent [publication](https://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Tel/Recoltes-et-Semailles-I-II) of Grothendieck's *Récoltes et Semailles*, I've been umm-ing and ah-ing about whether to get a copy, if only for the "soaking nuts" story.  My French reading is probably up to it, but I'm not an algebraic geometer (more functional analysis).  Could one get anything out of it without being steeped in the algebraic geometry?

Comment: It has nothing to do with algebraic geometry.

Comment: The review I read explains that the book mainly consists of an attempt of outreaching of the mathematical activity from the inside, as well as a criticism of the mathematical community and mystical thoughts, so I don't think it requires a deep knowledge of algebraic geometry.

Comment: If you want to get the flavour of it so that you can see whether it is for you, then [Where can you find Grothendieck's "Récoltes et Semailles"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52164/where-can-you-find-grothendiecks-r%c3%a9coltes-et-semailles) has some discussion of where to find it online.

Comment: Many thanks for the responses, I'll go and snag myself a copy then ...

Comment: @J.J.Green you can get a freshly edited and re-transcribed electronic version of R et S here: https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/ReS.pdf, done by Mateo Carmona