# Which mathematics book would you wish theoretical physicists had read?

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, textbook-recommendation

It is a well-known phenomenon that mathematicians and physicists working on closely-related topics (say in gauge theories, or in general relativity etc.) generally approach the problems from very different angles and often have trouble understanding each other.

In this light, which book(s) do you wish theoretical physicists working on topics intersecting your own research area had read so they could more readily appreciate your work and/or more easily explain their own work to you in terms accessible to you?

To avoid this being opinion-based, please explain what essential concepts or techniques the theoretical physicist would learn from this book(s).

Comment: I read this Book in 2012-2013 Alexei Kushner, et al.
Contact Geometry and Nonlinear Differential Equations https://www.amazon.fr/Contact-Geometry-Nonlinear-Differential-Equations/dp/0521824761

Comment: The best Book about Geometry of Quantization I read in 2013-2014 was N. M. J. Woodhouse
, Geometric Quantization, https://www.amazon.fr/Geometric-Quantization-N-M-Woodhouse/dp/0198502702

Comment: Generalized complex geometry, as developed by Hitchin, contains complex and symplectic geometry which are very useful for Geometry of 3-forms in 6-dimensions (I read them in 2012) https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0973

Comment: See the World of Daniel Friedan about Cosmology and Ricci flow https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pages/friedan/

Comment: Positivity theory(Positivity of semi flat metric) and Hitchin fibration is open reasarch domain which is used in advanced area of Mathematical Physics such as C.Vafa.  or Hausel   et al. https://www.physicsoverflow.org/39137/any-progress-on-strominger-yau-and-zaslow-conjecture

Comment: Gauged Linear Sigma Model https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://gokovagt.org/proceedings/2016/02ggt16-tianxu.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4583MvO3rAhUppIsKHbEJBg0QFjAJegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2b4z_RKTQhX1ONL2HpF0JE

Comment: I recall once hearing a physicist say that all functional analysts should read Dirac's Principles of Quantum Mechanics; he seemed sure that they had not all done so.

Comment: I somewhat dislike the implicit premise of this question, but maybe I am reading too much into it. My very inexpert impression is that theoretical physicists are actually ahead of most of us in using modern techniques.

Comment: I think it goes both ways - there's physics maths that doesn't yet exist as maths maths, and there's existing maths that physicists rediscover (sometimes over and over again). In any case, I explicitly also ask for the case where the reading would enable the physicist to better explain their own research to mathematicians.

Comment: @MarkWildon : I interpret the question to be analogous to a non-native speaker of English asking native English speakers for recommendations for a manual for idiomatic English that is geared toward speakers of English as a second language.

Comment: @HassanJolany Why don't you consolidate your comments into an answer?

Comment: @TimothyChow That's a nice analogy! Indeed the question is intended to be mostly about things that aid  communication between mathematicians, mathematical physicists, and theoretical physicists.

Comment: I find it interesting that nobody so far has suggested any book dealing with categories, sheaves or stacks. These provide mathematical languages that (with the [occasional] exception of categories) aren't used in physics, but are quite relevant to a fair amount of mathematics that does have a non-empty intersection with the mathematics of theoretical physics. I would have thought that knowing those languages would be rather useful for conversations between physicists and mathematicians.

Answer (score 10):

"*Les tenseurs*" by Laurent Schwartz. This is the best book on the subject and I often feel that physics books do not really make a good job at presenting tensors. Too bad it has no English translation.

Comment: Maybe I could translate it.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/17778/88133

Comment: @user1741137 that would be great, but I suspect there are rights to be obtained before you can get started.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum theory is an application of generalized probability theory (i.e., quantum logic). The most detailed introduction to this approach is: "Geometry of Quantum Theory", by V. S. Varadarajan
https://smile.amazon.com/Geometry-Quantum-Theory-V-Varadarajan/dp/0387961240/ref=sr_1_3?crid=7P7GHVPJLJ95&dchild=1&keywords=varadarajan+quantum&qid=1600337321&sprefix=Varadarjan%2Caps%2C194&sr=8-3

Comment: Second edition: https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Quantum-Theory-V-S-Varadarajan-dp-0387493859/dp/0387493859/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Answer (score 2):

Nakahara's *Geometry, Topology and Physics*.

It was chapter $10$ that allowed me to fully engage with connections on fibre bundles and the relationship to Gauge theories. The earlier chapters on Holonomy and de Rham Cohomology groups was instrumental in introducing these concepts from a Physics perspective for me in the early part of my PhD.

Comment: typos, though...

Comment: @AlexArvanitakis Yes, unfortunately this is very true....

Comment: Any hope for a revised edition?

Comment: There seems to be an unofficial list of errata at https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/profiles/johnsong/nakahara-errata-new-41775.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I always thought spinors were treated in a quite obscure way in physics. In particular it's difficult to make sense of the Dirac adjoint $\bar \psi= \psi^\dagger\gamma_0$ of a spinor (take a look at the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_adjoint) if you don't believe me) until one reads
an introductory book on Clifford algebras, particularly one which emphasizes the non-Euclidean case and the natural metric on spinors, like for instance [Garling](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/clifford-algebras-an-introduction/36A64283F11690E47A76775AF3561627)'s.