# Citation of a paper with a proof you would like to improve

Tags: mathematical-writing, journals, citations

Imagine that you are in the following situation: You write up a proof which eventually gets published. There you need a result which is not so well-known but it is contained in another paper P; therefore you just cite it. You read P and come to the conclusion: It's awful. You need plenty of time to insert the details or even correct it. It may also happen that the proof is somewhat too complicated because in your situation it is much easier. Maybe you have found a shorter proof, but based on the ideas in P. Now what do you do? Several options come into my mind:

- Just cite the paper without any further explanation.
- Cite the paper but give a short hint how to simplify the arguments.
- Cite the paper but give a more elaborate explanation of the arguments.
- Write up the details of the proof of the desired result in your situation and remark somewhere that it was inspired by the paper P.

For each option there are pros and cons. For example, you don't want to blow up your proof with material which does not seem be so important. Also, you don't want to bore your readers. This favors the first options. On the other hand, you might want to be sure that the readers understand the argument and don't have to read P. This favors the last options. What do you think, which option is your favorite and why? Also, are there other appropriate options?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty wide-open discussion/advice/opinion kind of question.  I think the literature is a pretty broad landscape, and depending on your situation any number of possibilities would be appropriate.   

Comment: If you care enough to ask on MO, I'd say put the improved proof in your paper. "For the convenience of the reader, we now recall the proof of [Awful 2009, lemma 3]..."

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, and the same is true for all other questions which were asked so far under these tags ;).

Comment: Definitely choose option 4. If the result is not so well known anyway, it deserves to be appear in another paper. Also, if you can improve the proof, this is something everyone should see.

Comment: In these situations, I usually choose option #2 or #3. If the basic result is in P, #4 seems to be a bit disingenuous. After all, the author of P did obtain some version of the result, albeit clumsily. On the other hand, since P is after all awful and not quite the right thing in your context, something beyond #1 is probably necessary in order for many of your readers to follow your argument successfully.... What Berger suggests is also an elegant solution.

Comment: I would agree with Spiro. Indeed, I believe that most of the time, one should stick to "One idea - one paper".
Otherwise, there's a risk that one of the ideas gets unremarked.


Comment: @Martin, the point being it's not clear there's anything specific to mathematics here.  It's just a general academic writing question. 

Comment: @Ryan: Ok, but again this also applies to other questions asked on MO (without any close-vote). For example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43147/citing-papers-that-are-in-a-language-that-you-do-not-read

Comment: **Meta** thread in case there is need for further discussion http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1225/

Comment: We all stand on the shoulders of giants. The first proof of a result can be awful for a number of reasons eg:
(1) the proper language/formalism for the proof (which may trivialize it) was only invented later
(2) the proof follows the intuition of how it was thought up and so may, for instance, have case-by-case analysis or ugly computations in coordinates
(3) the author may have been in a rush to beat the competition and so the result is unpolished 
(4) common folklore of the time may be lost and so details that would have been obvious then are not so now
Just be fair to the original. 

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: good points, which remind of something I read (I think in Littlewood's Miscellany, attributed to Besicovitch) which was along the lines of "a mathematician's quality can be measured in terms of the number of bad proofs he has published" -- the argument being that the ground-breaking work is messy. That said, I think it's a shame if there isn't some avenue/outlet for people to improve on past proofs; and sometimes when writing a paper I want to give a reference that best helps the reader who wants to learn more.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Improving existing proofs is an important and undervalued part of mathematics.  We don't just want to know *whether* something is true; we want to know *why* it's true.  So I think that if you have a better proof of something, you should find a way to share it with the world.

Here are a couple of thoughts about the practicalities, to add to Andrew's suggestion about the nLab.

First, you could put the simplified proof into an appendix to your paper.  I quite like appendices, as both a reader and a writer.  Used well, they help to keep the main part of the paper flowing, while providing crucial details to those who want them.

Second, it's entirely possible that the author of [Awful 2009] will referee your paper.  So whatever you write, you need to keep them sweet.  I think this also favours the appendix option.

Comment: @Tom: This is a very nice idea, thanks!

Comment: I agree with Tom. I have given new, simpler proofs (albeit probably not of highly important results) in appendices. While it certainly is important (and essential) to cite the original source, when most of us look up a proof, we go to the version that's the clearest and most elegant, which is almost by necessity never the original source.

Answer (score 8):

Since this has been reopened, I'm going to repeat what I said in the meta thread before this question gets closed again:

> stick the simplified proof on the nLab and cite that

This is a completely serious suggestion.  You have an improved version of the proof (whether it is *globally* improved or just *locally* improved[1]).  It's not "original research" so an "Established Journal" might be reluctant to publish it[2].  But hordes of other mathematicians will be interested in reading it so it should be put somewhere that they can find it.  This seems a perfect fit for the nLab.

If you have it written in reasonably standard LaTeX, I can even help you get it into the right formatting.

[1] A *global* improvement is one that anyone reading the original proof would be interested in, a *local* improvement is one that anyone reading your result that depends on it would be interested in.

[2] Insert standard rant about journals here.

Comment: And of course you should *also* cite the original paper if you do this.

Comment: I don't see why that needs saying.  Surely that's just normal citation convention.  Simplified proofs are often published, especially when they shed new light on the original, and in those cases it's quite normal to say "... due originally to *X*, but see *Y* for a gentle introduction" (or whatever).

Comment: But does the nLab really welcome contributions that might not conform with the nLab point of view? In light of http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/nPOV, I would think not. 

Comment: Yeah, I've always wondered why the nLab people are so aggressive in trying to get people whose work has nothing to do with category theory to post there.  Shouldn't their suggestion be "start your own subject-specific wiki"?

Comment: If I actually thought that answering either Joel's or Andy's comments would make any difference, then I would as those are extremely easy points to answer.  But instead I think I'll get on with writing a page on the nLab that lies on the interface between differential topology and functional analysis and has absolutely no categorical content whatsoever.

Comment: Andrew, I am sorry if my comment has irked you; this was not at all my intention. Rather, it was a serious question.  Namely, the nLab seems perfect for the use you mention in your answer, provided that the topic of the post is in harmony with the nPOV. And to be sure, this includes a lot of excellent mathematics, which I have enjoyed at the nLab. But meanwhile, there is also a lot of work arising from a perspective at odds with the nLab view, such as most research in set theory, and my sense is that such posts are not really wanted at the nLab. Isn't this correct? 

Comment: Apology accepted, and insert standard comment about comments at MO being lousy places for discussions!  What defines the nLab as far as I'm concerned is that it is for *working* mathematicians.  If you wanted to make some notes there on a topic in set theory then you'd be most welcome to do so.  There is a danger that someone might come along and **add** something a bit nPov-y to it (note the "add", no-one would take away) but to avoid that all you'd have to do is register on the nForum and say, "I'm writing a page on *X* and I'd like to keep it as 'pure set theory'." then the most (ctd)


Comment: (ctd) that would happen is that someone would maybe rename it to make it clear that it was from a particular perspective, and probably someone else would write a *different* page with the nPOV version and link the two.  If that's not distinct enough, then we actually have several distinct "wikis" at the nlab which can be interlinked but have different flavours (most are "personal").  You could ask to start one - I think you'd be welcome, though I only speak for myself - and then you'd get the benefit of cross-linking when you wanted it without fear of your stuff being overwritten.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey : I also was not trying to offend.  Like Joel, my own research (on geometric topology and geometric group theory) seems at odds with the nPOV.  This is not meant as a criticism of the nPOV, which I understand as a statement of shared interest rather than a statement that "all math that doesn't fit into this box is bad".  Is the statement of the nPOV not reflective of the current intentions of the nLAB (which even has n-categories in its name)?  I've just always been puzzled by the insistence by nLAB people that people whose research has no connection to nLAB type stuff

Comment: (continued) would want to post there instead of some more appropriate venue.  Maybe you should encourage the creation of other wiki type places?

Comment: (the above comments were being composed when Andrew Stacey posted his reply to Joel)

Comment: Re my first sentence: Tom Leinster has started a discussion at the nForum from this.  You're welcome to join in (non-registered posts are allowed).  http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Mathforge/nForum/comments.php?DiscussionID=3342

Comment: With Andrew, I'd prefer to have this discussion at the nForum, but in case there's no migration there, let me say that mathematicians like Joel and Andy are heartily encouraged to IGNORE the nPOV, if it suits them. And having a personal web at ncatlab, to write up notes on what one jolly well pleases, is also strongly encouraged. And now I'm going to go to the nForum... 

Answer (score 5):

The first question is whether your are bringing new ideas to the party. If so, then you add your new proof and trust that the referees do not get to picky about space constraints.
So you are in Case 4.

If there are no new ideas, but the proof can be significantly simplified in your situation
things are a little greyer. I would still say that you are in Case 4.

If the problem is that the original paper is a dog's breakfast, then I feel you just have
to hold your nose and cite it; you're in Case 1. (If you want to correct other people's work, someone must have homework lying around waiting to be marked...) In this case I think there is an argument that by reproving the original result you are making a kind of weak claim to it. Other authors might cite you when they should really cite the original.

In the case where you are offering more than improved exposition, it is mainly the space constraints that apply. I do not see any ethical issue then.

[In reference to some of the comments. Of course improving exposition is very valuable. But I
cannot think of any reasonable journal that would accept an article consisting of an improved exposition of an accepted result, unless it introduced new ideas. I am not defending
this situation, but it is a fact.]

Comment: I would say that terrible written papers do not deserve to be cited. And regarding space constraints - let the editor decide. If they tell you to shorten your paper, the version on arXive is still there for grad students to read.

In other words - most of the time I would go with option 4.

Comment: @r0b0t, you are certainly entitled to your opinion, but if a result is proved somewhere (one knows that) and one uses it then one has to cite that paper. This is not a judgement call based on the perceived expostitory quality of that paper. (One might add remarks or clarfication if one thinks it is needed, but one has to cite!) Of course, there are situations, like related work, where one has some flexibility to cite or not and there one might or might not take such considerations into account, but for a proper result one uses there is no room for any considerations whether one cites or not. 

Comment: -1: Surely if the original paper is a dog's breakfast, and you can simplify it greatly, the mathematical community deserves to have the simplification available to it. And of course, you should give full credit to the original author, but if other people cite the simplified paper and not the original, it's really in part the original author's fault for not writing it up better in the first place.

Comment: Just for clarification: I do not think that terrible papers should not be cited, I think that they just don't deserve it. I like the answer given by Tom Leinster; in my opinion any improved exposition of anything should appear somewhere. ;)

Comment: @rObOt : I strongly disagree even with your weaker statement.  If an author has proven a result, then they deserve credit for it whether or not they are good writers.

Comment: +1 Andy. Sometimes the breakthrough of realizing something *can* be done, and bludgeoning the problem into submission, is what's needed to inspire people to write "elegant" or "better" proofs. Over the course of time (50+years) people may start to make references to the original briefer and briefer, but I think it should always be done, just out of good manners

Comment: For anyone reading these comments: I have in mind something like the examples of polynomially bounded operators which are not completely polynomially bounded. The best place to get a feel for concrete examples is the paper of Davidson and Paulsen, but original credit should IMHO always rest with the path-breaking work of Pisier, even if his tour de force is not the most useful for someone writing a paper (and some subsequent simplifications of Kislyakov should probably be acknowledged).